# how to display bootstrap popover on fullcalendar time slot click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar with bootstrap. I am trying to implement calendar similar to google calendar. I could successfully display the popover on dayclick and eventclick in monthly view.

I am trying to use the select event of weekly view to display bootstrap popover near the time slot. The popover will display date and from time and to time from the selection and will accept the agenda from user, but in the select event I do not get the element to which I can bind popover.

Can somebody please help me to fix this?

Comment: Post code so we can see what's going on and what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you select a range in week view there is not element yet.

You can check it [in the source code at line 6744](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/blob/master/dist/fullcalendar.js#L6744).

It just render a highlight underneath the table cells.

I think you could work in two options:

1. Use the coordinates you receive in [select callback jsEvent](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_callback/) to create your custom tooltip.
2. Create a temporary event to attach the tooltip to it. Later you will discard this element when you save/cancel the selection.